# Equivalent function to IFERROR in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column which is a substring of a large amount of text.

I want to pull out the 4 characters that should be the year in YYYY format.

If the text is incorrect it could have a text in it making it a string.

I want to compare the year to the current year and I can't do that as the data types are different.

`TRY_PARSE` isn't a built in function.

Also tried a few variations of:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Text, 46, 4) AS Year, 
CASE WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Text, 46, 4) AS INT) IS NULL THEN 'Error'
WHEN CAST(Year AS INT) IS NULL < YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 'In the past'
ELSE 'In the future'
END TEXT 
FROM TABLE


Example column:

    Year
    2011
    2018
    2022
    D200

Example output required:

Output

    'In the past'
    'In the past'
    'In the future'
    'Error'
```

Comment: Where is the problem? WHEN (CAST YEAR AS INT) = YEAR(GETDATE()) ?? --->>> Throws an error! Thanks to @Larnu

Comment: "TRY_PARSE isn't a built in function" which version are you using?

Comment: If you `CAST` the value `'D200` to an `int`, @nabuchodonossor, you get an error.

Comment: @Larnu Assuming the OP (or any future reader) be using a sufficiently recent version of SQL Server.

Comment: Hadn't realised that Ezlo was quoting, @TimBiegeleisen. This however, implies the OP is using an unsupported version, as `TRY_PARSE` is in every supported version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming any year between `0000` and `9999` be acceptable as valid years, you could just use `LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(Text, 46, 4) NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
         THEN 'Error'
         WHEN CAST(SUBSTRING(Text, 46, 4) AS INT) < YEAR(GETDATE())
         THEN 'In the past'
         ELSE 'In the future' END AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 4):

I *think* you want `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,[Text]) < YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 'In the Past'
            WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,[Text]) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 'Current Year'
            WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,[Text]) > YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 'In The Future',
            ELSE 'Error'
      END
FROM YourTable;
```